# How to adjust the graceful shutdown period in sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, sidecar, graceful-shutdown

Would like to know if there are any setting to adjust the graceful shutdown period for sidecar container in kubernetes? As we have found out that the period is too short and want to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`

From docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podspec-v1-core):

> **terminationGracePeriodSeconds**
>
> integer   Optional duration in seconds the pod needs to terminate
> gracefully. May be decreased in delete request. Value must be
> non-negative integer. The value zero indicates delete immediately. If
> this value is nil, the default grace period will be used instead. The
> grace period is the duration in seconds after the processes running in
> the pod are sent a termination signal and the time when the processes
> are forcibly halted with a kill signal. Set this value longer than the
> expected cleanup time for your process. Defaults to 30 seconds.

---

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: test
        name: test
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60  # <----HERE
```

---

Additionally you may also want to check the docs about [container lifecycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/).